# Client side decorations are not removed in some gtk apps

Tags: 20.04, unity, gtk, gtk3

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop and also have `gtk3-nocsd` package installed. But some programs like `bulky` which I have downloaded from Linux Mint website work with this and show CSD instead.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhGPp.jpg)

As you can see in the screenshot, `mintinstall` works fine although it's also a Linux Mint application, but some others like `bulky` or `lollypop` do not. How can this be solved?

Comment: I have the same problem with Meld and this is quite annoying as I use it very often. Have you found a fix for this? Or just a relevant documentation of what the problem is precisely?

Comment: @njames the only solution I've found is to use Ubuntu Unity iso for installation, which contains patches for this issue. It's possible that such patch can be somehow applied to the current host system, but I yet have to find the way to do that.
Nevertheless, I have moved to KDE instead. Unity is getting pretty rough around the edges, and most of the bugs are not really getting fixed.